# How to plot the hour of the sunsets

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, astronomy

i have this code:

```
city = Entity["City",{"Santiago","Santiago","Chile"}]
start = {2013, 1, 1, 0, 0}
end = {2015, 12, 31, 0, 0}
data = Sunset[city, DateRange[DateObject[start], DateObject[end], 10], TimeZone -> 0]
```

Now I don't know how to plot hour vs date when the sunset occurs. What do I have to do now?

Thanks! :D

Comment: Try `DateListPlot[{DateObject[#1], DateValue[#2, "Hour"]} & @@@ data["Path"]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you!!! :D That's what I wanted... How do I choose it as the answer?

Comment: Alright, I'll post something later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To settle this: there is a more compact way to generate the required plot than the snippet in my comment.

```
DateListPlot[TimeSeriesMap[DateValue[#, "Hour"] &, data]]
```

[image: sunset hours over two years]

Comment: Is the data correct? Compare it with [this](https://ptaff.ca/soleil/?l1pays=Chile&l1etat=&l1ville=Santiago&l2pays=&l2etat=&l1cityname=Santiago%2C+Chile&l1ltd=33&l1ltm=25&l1lts=59&l1ltx=S&l1lgd=70&l1lgm=39&l1lgs=59&l1lgx=W&l1tz=-4.0&l1dst=CL&l2cityname=&l2ltd=&l2ltm=&l2lts=&l2ltx=N&l2lgd=&l2lgm=&l2lgs=&l2lgx=E&l2tz=0&l2dst=&year=2016&month=03&day=14&lang=en_CA&go=Show+the+graph!) for example...

Comment: Not sure; unfortunately I don't see a way to obtain historical data from that website.

Comment: With `DateValue[#, "Hour"] &` you're rounding to whole hours only. I'd do sth like `(DateValue[#, "Hour"] + DateValue[#, "Minute"]/60) &` to get a smooth curve.